# JavaScript implementation of OGC GeoSPARQL functions

Tags: javascript, geosparql

I am aware of various Java implementations of OGC GeoSPARQL standard, provided by RDF4J, Jena, GraphDB and other vendors. Now I am looking for JavaScript libraries that implement whole set of GeoSPARQL functions, or some subset of them.